# Is there any point to continuing with an interview when I'm sure that I won't join the company?

Tags: interviewing

My current situation is that I've already signed a contract with Company A, when Company B called. Company B interests me, although I've decided to stay with Company A.

However, they've called me in for an interview, and I said yes. My main reason for this is so that I could see the office for myself, and have additional data for my market worth.

So aside from that, is there any point to continuing with an interview when I'm sure that I won't join the company?

---

Additional info : They know I already have signed a contract as I've told them, but they said they still want to go for an interview.

Comment: @KentAnderson Not quite the same, this is asking whether it's worth going to the interview at all.

Comment: It's always good to practice/refresh your interview skills, so that's another reason why you might opt to continue.

Comment: Hi all, I've added crucial info that I forgot to include. See edit.

Comment: Your update changes the dynamics of this situation drastically. Did Company B give a reason why they still want you to come in? Maybe they want to impress you so you'll consider them in 1-2 years when you're ready to move on, and that would be both flattering and worthwhile. However, if they want to try and convince you to break off a signed contract with Company A that's a huge red flag.

Comment: It's only a complete waste of time if you treat it as such. If you try to make a fantastic impression on Company B that might be remembered if you ever need to apply with them again.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can be honest with them. Explain that you are genuinely interested in the position and the company. But, you are no longer available. Ask them if it would be OK to have a short or more informal conversation where you can each learn more about each other and discover whether there may be opportunities in the future. This is called networking. It is essential for your career. But, always be honest.

Answer (score 4):

No.  There is no point in continuing to interview with them.

1. "I could see the office for myself" - I am sure it is very nice, but is it as nice as the beach, mountains, movie theater, etc., or any of the other nice places you could spend that time.
2. "have additional data for my market worth" - Since you are sure that you won't join them, what does their number matter?  Apparently even if they offered $1 billion you would turn them down.  You should only care about the numbers from companies you might actually accept.

Comment: While 2 does have a valid point, it may also be illuminating for the OP to discover what their salary offer would be at this company, which may help them understand if their expectation is too high or low. Similarly I've known people use an interview process to "test" how far they can push their requested salary. I don't recommend either of these things, but that doesn't mean they don't happen and have no utility.

Comment: `Apparently even if they offered $1 billion you would turn them down.`  For that kind of money, I would use the money to buy out the other contract and have plenty left over.  Plus, reminds me of the Dilbert cartoon where Dogbert agrees to be CEO for $1/year provided compensation is paid in advance and there is no mandatory retirement age.

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no point continuing and beyond that it's rude. If you've already signed a contract then going to a second interview is a complete waste of their time, and you've been untruthful with them as to the potential end result. Companies who are hiring tend to spend a lot of time and energy trying to weed out the noise and find the candidate is right for them.

Regardless of any potential "informational gain" or "practice" you might have from the second interview, it is a completely selfish act that ultimately costs them time (and as a result: money). There are any number of other ways to accomplish this without going to this length. As a matter of professional courtesy you should discontinue any interviews and/or negotiations once you have made the determination that you would not accept their offer.

I don't know your industry or your market, but this world is a lot smaller than some would like to think. This kind of thing can actually turn into a career killer if done with the wrong time, company or person.